# ReactJS Replace content

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I have a field that displays a date using the following component:

```
import React from 'react';
import Moment from 'moment';

export default class ChaserField extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div onClick={this.props.onClick}>
                {this.props.chaserDate != '0000-00-00' && this.props.chaserDate ? Moment(this.props.chaserDate).format('DD/MM/YYYY') : '-'}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

The parent:

```
import React from 'react';
import Moment from 'moment';
import TrackingSentField from './TrackingSentField';
import ChaserField from './ChaserField';

export default class ShippingTable extends React.Component {
    static contextTypes = {}

    componentWillMount() {
        this.setState({
            editingChaser: false,
            editingTrackingSent: false
        })
    }

    handleTrackingSentField(e) {
        this.setState({
            editingTrackingSent: true
        })
    }

    handleChaserField(e) {
        this.setState({
            editingChaser: true
        })
    }

    render() {
        var rowData = this.props.rows.map((row) => {
            return (
                <tr key={row.id}>
                    <td>{row.position_ref}</td>
                    <td>{row.quantity}</td>
                    <td><a target="_blank" href={'/supplier/'+row.supplierId}>{row.name}</a></td>
                    <td>{row.warehouse_eta != '0000-00-00' && row.warehouse_eta ? Moment(row.warehouse_eta).format('DD/MM/YYYY') : '-'}</td>
                    <td>{row.customer_eta != '0000-00-00' && row.customer_eta ? Moment(row.customer_eta).format('DD/MM/YYYY') : '-'}</td>
                    <td><ChaserField onClick={this.handleChaserField.bind(this)} chaserDate={row.chaserETA}/></td>
                    <td><TrackingSentField onClick={this.handleTrackingSentField.bind(this)} trackingDate={row.customer_tracking}/></td>
                    <td><img title={row.img_title} src={row.img}/></td>
                </tr>
            )
        });
        return (
            <table className="table table-condensed table-hover">
                <thead>
                <col width="40"/>
                <col width="50"/>
                <col width="230"/>
                <col width="80"/>
                <col width="80"/>
                <col width="80"/>
                <col width="80"/>
                <col width="53"/>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>QTY</th>
                    <th>Supplier</th>
                    <th>WETA</th>
                    <th>CETA</th>
                    <th>Chase</th>
                    <th>Track' sent</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <col width="40"/>
                <col width="50"/>
                <col width="230"/>
                <col width="80"/>
                <col width="80"/>
                <col width="80"/>
                <col width="80"/>
                <col width="53"/>
                {rowData}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        )
    }
}
```

What I want to happen is when I click on the div, it's contents to change to a date input field, and when the user is finished changing the date for it to save when they click off it or hit enter.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have most of the things in place. In the parent component you have in the state the value `editingChaser` which you can pass as a prop to the child (e.g. `<ChaserField editMode={this.state.editingChaser} ... />`

In the child component, you can use the `editMode` prop to either render what you have now, or an `<input />` field (when `editMode` is true).

You'd also probably want to store the edited content in the parent component, so you'd need to pass an `onSave` callback to update the edited value in the parent component. You can assign that callback to the `onBlur` prop of the input for example, or to the `onClick` of a button next to the input, if you prefer the changes to be explicitly "committed" by the user.

Comment: Does hitting enter trigger the onBlur event?

Comment: No I don't think it does. To get that you'd need to check the key code which is part of the keypress event. Alternatively, you could wrap your input in a form and use the form onSubmit callback, which will probably be triggered by pressing enter. Maybe the event key code approach would be more robust.

Comment: Doing that would be much simpler than sticking an even listener on the window? i.e. window.addEventListener('mousedown', this.props.pageClick.bind(this), false);

Comment: You don't need to set an event listener on the window object for that, you want react to handle all this stuff for you at the element level. If you start to do things "manually" with "addEventListener" you won't take advantage of React. Also, you probably need ```onKeyUp``` and not mousedown.

Comment: As another unrelated note, it would be better to set the initial state for your ```ShippingTable ``` as part of the ```constructor``` method, not in componentWillMount. See here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#es6-classes

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like (untested, but you should be able to see the general idea):

```
import React from 'react';
import Moment from 'moment';

export default class ChaserField extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const { editing, toggle, chaserDate, update } = this.props;

        let content = null;

        if(!editing) {
            // Viewing
            const value = chaserDate != '0000-00-00' && chaserDate ? Moment(chaserDate).format('DD/MM/YYYY') : '-';
            content = <div onClick={toggle}>{value}</div>;
        } else {
            // Editing
            // Not sure if you want this raw or formatted, adjsut as needed
            content = <input onBlur={toggle} value={chaserDate} onChange={update} />;
        }

        return content;
    }
}

// -- In parent ------------------------
// 
// Callback rigging
toggle() {
    this.setState({
        editing: !this.state.editing;
    })
}
updateDate(e) {
    this.setState({
        chaserDate: e.target.value;
    })
}


// ...  down in render
const { editing, chaserDate } = this.state;
const { updateDate, toggle } = this;
<ChaserField editing={editing} toggle={toggle} update={updateDate} chaserDate={chaserDate} />
```